# Raspbian OS reboot issues with A83T processor system

Tags: reboot

We are using Raspbian OS in our A83T processor system. When we giving reboot command system hangs. Please find the log below

```
bpi-iot-ros-ai login: root
Password: 
Last login: Thu Sep 19 20:32:42 CST 2019 on ttyS0
Linux bpi-iot-ros-ai 3.4.39-BPI-M3-Kernel #31 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 9 10:25:59 IST 2019 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
root@bpi-iot-ros-ai:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
3              4              1              3
root@bpi-iot-ros-ai:~# echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
root@bpi-iot-ros-ai:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
8              4              1              3
root@bpi-iot-ros-ai:~# reboot
[  347.969896] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[  348.037611] systemd-journald[195]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[  348.444580] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[  348.800459] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[  348.808490] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting /sys/fs/fuse/connections.
[  348.900299] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting /sys/kernel/config.
[  348.907497] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting /sys/kernel/debug.
[  348.914609] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting /dev/mqueue.
[  348.991735] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[  349.057659] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[  349.064131] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[  349.070601] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[  349.077178] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[  349.083568] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[  349.089742] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[  349.105523] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[  349.112193] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[  349.119080] systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
[  349.134188] systemd-shutdown[1]: Rebooting.
[  349.139161] drivers/cpufreq/autohotplug.c:reboot_notifier_call: stop autoplug begin
[  349.148207] drivers/cpufreq/autohotplug.c:reboot_notifier_call: stop autoplug done
[  349.157131] drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c:reboot_notifier_call: stop none boot cpus
[  349.314245] CPU1: shutdown
[  349.514519] CPU2: shutdown
[  349.653947] CPU3: shutdown
[  349.856343] CPU4: shutdown
[  350.051237] CPU5: shutdown
[  350.251161] CPU6: shutdown
[  350.341119] CPU7: shutdown
[  350.346994] drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c:reboot_notifier_call: stop none boot cpus done
[  350.356090] [mmc]: shutdown_mmc: is not card 2, return
[  350.362002] [mmc]: shutdown_mmc: mmc 0 shutdown exit..ok
[  350.367986] [mmc]: try to disable cache
[  350.372386] [mmc]: sdc2 set ios: clk 50000000Hz bm PP pm ON vdd 3.3V width 8 timing LEGACY(SDR12) dt B
[  350.382998] [mmc]: sdc2 set ios: clk 50000000Hz bm PP pm ON vdd 3.3V width 1 timing LEGACY(SDR12) dt B
[  350.393524] [mmc]: sdc2 set ios: clk 400000Hz bm PP pm ON vdd 3.3V width 1 timing LEGACY(SDR12) dt B
[  350.403940] [mmc]: sdc2 set ios: clk 400000Hz bm PP pm ON vdd 3.3V width 1 timing LEGACY(SDR12) dt B
[  350.416712] [mmc]: sdc2 set ios: clk 400000Hz bm PP pm ON vdd 3.3V width 1 timing LEGACY(SDR12) dt B
[  350.480352] [mmc]: shutdown_mmc: mmc 2 shutdown exit..ok
[  350.710833] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  350.715166] Restarting system.
[  350.718598] 
[  350.720302] Restarting Linux version 3.4.39-BPI-M3-Kernel (root@Haber) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #31 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 9 10:25:59 IST 2019
[  350.720310]
```

Please let me know, what could be the issues.

Comment: Raspbian only runs on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This forum is for Raspberry Pi specific questions, not running software on other machines.

Comment: You are also clearly **not** using the Raspbian kernel, so this really does not belong here.  Try our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as indicated by the comments, could be that Raspian is specific for Raspberry Pis. Although you might get it running on a different system, it is likely that you run into problems, especially at boot time or with IO.

We do not know a lot about your system. It may not even support rebooting. The A83T is "based on" the A7, so you would probably have to use an image for the Pi 2. But I have no idea how compatible the A83T is with the A7.